# Форма в блоке и mvc в yii

Tags: php, yii

Здравствуйте.
Представим есть страница и ее основное содержимое -  форма контакта.
Для этой формы все понятно: По текущему пути, внутри найденного контроллера/действия, создается модель формы и обрабатывается сабмит(если произошел) или модель формы передается в нужный вид для отображения формы пользователю.
Но например в левом сайдбаре у меня в блоке тоже есть какая то форма, например логина.
Как с ней то быть?
По умолчанию что yii предлагает (но как то сомнения вызывает у меня):
В файле слоя (layout) выводится виджет формы.
Класс этого виджета в его методе run() делает все тоже что и Контроллер из первого примера. Т.е. виджет работает как контроллер.

Comment: А где вы собираетесь совершать обработку введенных данных, кроме как в контроллере? На то он и MVC, чтоб каждый занимался своим делом.

Comment: И в виджете, и в контроллере. Только каждый заберет только что ему предназначается.

Comment: Eugene, как текущий контроллер (а у нас он только и есть) может знать о какой то форме, выведенной в лайауте?

Comment: Может в форме авторизации стоит прописать url на... допустим /login ? )) ну а после авторизации редиректить на предыдущую страницу. Ну а случае, если некорректно были введены данные, уже на самой странице login выводить об этом сообщения

Comment: Это очень глупое решение. Если есть какая то форма, то заводить для нее отдельную страницу, доступную извне (и поисковикам в том числе). И на этой странице дубляж функционала нужен получается, не пустая же страница. Плюс на нее кидать сабмит, а потом редиректить при ошибке назад - это кривое решение. Только новичек в веб разработке может такое предложить.
Впрочем кроме капитанстра от @IVsevolod типа то что форма отправляет $_POST данные тут я ничего по теме и не услышал

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу никаких проблем. Форма запихивает свои данные в массив GET, в элемнт со своим именем. При разборе данных из формы смотрите откуда они, принимая или не принимая их, соответственно.

```
$_GET['form_1']['val1']
$_GET['form_2']['valxxx']
```

Более конкретно смогу ответить после уточнений и, возможно, исходного кода.

Comment: Я же не спрашивал о том как технически по разным именам сабмит обрабатывать, это и так понятно. Я спрашивал как и где саму форму создавать и где писать код обработки сакбмитаю.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно неправильно понял вопрос. И думаю, Вам следует перечитать [документацию Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/basics.mvc), все их советы по использованию самого фреймворка.

Сама структура по представлению Yii фреймворка вот такая:

[image: Статическая структура приложения Yii]

А на странице "[Лучшие практики MVC](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/ru/basics.best-practices)" можно много интересного вычитать. Несколько моментов сюда выложу.

**Модель**

В общем случае, модели не должны напрямую взаимодействовать с пользователем. То есть:

- не должны использовать $_GET, $_POST или другие подобные переменные, напрямую получаемые из запроса пользователя, так как модели могут использоваться в совершенно других подприложениях (например, в модульных тестах или API), в которых эти переменные недоступны. Все переменные, относящиеся к запросу пользователя, должны обрабатываться в контроллере;
- не должны генерировать HTML или другой код представления, так как он может изменяться в зависимости от нужд пользователя (то есть, пользовательская часть и административная часть могут показывать новости в совершенно разном формате). Такой код должен генерироваться в представлениях.

**Представление**

Представления отвечают за отображение моделей в необходимом пользователю формате. В общем случае представления

- должны, главным образом, содержать разметку, такую как HTML, и простой PHP код, используемый для обхода, форматирования и отображения данных;
- не должны напрямую обращаться к базе данных. Этим должны заниматься модели;
- не должны напрямую обращаться к $_GET, $_POST и другим переменным, получаемым из запроса пользователя. Эту задачу должен выполнять контроллер. Представления должны использоваться только для оформления данных, полученных от контроллера и модели;
- могут напрямую обращаться к свойствам и методам контроллера или моделей. Однако это должно делаться только в целях отображения данных.

> **Виджеты**: используются в том случае, когда часть шаблона включает в себя слишком много логики. При этом логика переносится в класс виджета. Виджет, генерирующий большое количество разметки, может использовать свои шаблоны представлений.

**Контроллер**

Контроллеры — связующее звено, соединяющее модели, представления и другие компоненты в рабочее приложение. Контроллер отвечает за обработку запросов пользователя. Поэтому контроллер

- может обращаться к $_GET, $_POST и другим переменным PHP, получаемым из запроса пользователя;
- может создавать экземпляры моделей и управлять ими. К примеру, в типичном действии обновления модели контроллер может сначала создать экземпляр модели, затем заполнить его данными из $_POST и, в случае успешного сохранения модели, перенаправить браузер пользователя на страницу созданной модели. Стоит отметить, что само сохранение модели должно быть реализовано в классе модели, а не в контроллере;
- не должен содержать SQL-запросы. Их лучше держать в моделях;
- не должен содержать HTML и другую разметку. Её стоит вынести в представления.

---

> Но например в левом сайдбаре у меня в блоке тоже есть какая то форма, например логина.

Есть форма, но у нее свой id, свои параметры и своя ссылка. Т.е. ее данные уйдут в контроллер.

Comment: > Есть форма, но у нее свой id, свои параметры и своя ссылка. Т.е. ее данные уйдут в контроллер.

В какой контроллер ?

Comment: @craftman в тот, куда стоит адрес. Т.е. при формировании формы вы ставите, к примеру, `action="site/login"` то уйдет в SiteController в actionLogin с параметрами этой формы; если на этой же странице есть форма с регистрацией, с адресом `action="site/reg"` то уйдет в SiteController в actionReg уже с теми данными, что в форме регистрации.

Comment: Так не годится. Форма хоть и в блоке, но это не значит что нужен при сабмите редирект куда то(это я решу сам уже потом). Action должен быть у этой формы такой же как у текущей страницы. Ошибки теже мне же нужно на этой же странице показать, а не на какой то, куда отослано. 
Это стандартное поведение, как в друпал и других цмс.

Comment: Уточните что вам не подходит. "site/login" и "site/reg" это всего лишь кусок параметров, без ЧПУ по умолчанию они будут примерно так выглядеть: 

> index.php?r=site/login

после прохода какого то действия, в контроллере можно сделать редирект на нужную. И естественно при нахождении на странице регистрации, форма с регистрации адресуется на себя же, просто с параметрами, и так же можете сделать ajax отправку и многое другое 

> Ошибки теже мне же нужно на этой же странице показать

$this->redirect('site/profile')

Я не понимаю, почему после регистрации человек должен остаться на той же страниц

Comment: А человеку будет непонятно почему он форму в блоке отправил, а его перекинуло на какую то другую страницу.
Вообще формы выводить в которых action поуказывать на другие страницы - сильно упрощенный вариант и не рабочий в общем случае.
Например про ошибки вы мне не ответили. Редирект то идет обычно после успешного сабмита, а у нас ошибки, мы должны остаться на той же странице.

Comment: Вон посмотрите первый попавшийся сайт на друпале:
http://wkusno.org/node?destination=node
И как работает его форма входа.
Никаких переходов непонятно куда. Переход только при успешном сабмите и то, только если это Действительно требуется.
Это стандартное и логичное поведение.

Comment: Если не надо переправлять на другую страницу, не переправляйте. Я же говорю, используйте тогда ajax запросы, без перезагрузок страниц. Но эти запросы же не обязательно должны идти на ту же страницу по адресу.

Comment: @IVsevolod 

> Если не надо переправлять на другую страницу, не переправляйте.

Тогда возвращаемся к первоначальному вопросу. Вы же мне дали совет только как похожее реализовать с перенаправлением на другие страницы. Он негодится. AJAX - это тоже совсем другое. Я где то что ли говорил что мне нужна аякс форма???

Вообще конечно удивительно что такие элементарные вещи для CMF и даже для CMS в yii фреймворке вызывают такие проблемы для реализации. Как то поближе к нуждам сайтостроения этому фреймворку не помешало бы быть.

Comment: @craftman

> Вон посмотрите первый попавшийся сайт на друпале: http://wkusno.org/node?destination=node И как работает его форма входа

там идет POST запрос на сервер

> AJAX - это тоже совсем другое

у меня ощущение что я чего то не знаю и не догоняю.

> В файле слоя (layout) выводится виджет формы

Виджет создается чтобы не дублировать код отображения в разных частях.

> Я где то что ли говорил что мне нужна аякс форма?

Вы до конца не определились с тем, что вам нужно. По вопросу не понятно (кстати перечитайте его и дополните его, что вам нужно и что не понятно)

Answer (score 2):

Можно через базовый контроллер.

Добавить в него что-то типа:

```
public $contactForm;

public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    $this->contactForm = new ContactForm();
    if (isset($_POST['ContactForm'])) {
        $this->contactForm->attributes = $_POST['ContactForm'];
        if ($this->contactForm->validate()) {
            // Что-то куда-то отправляем
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Форма будет обрабатываться для любого action-а любого контроллера, который наследуется от базового. В layout-е модель для построения формы будет доступна через `$this->contactForm`.

Comment: а чисто из спортивного интереса - какой способ лучше - ваш или через виджет?

Comment: Работать будут оба способа.

Но, на мой взгляд, делать подобные вещи в виджете не лучший вариант. В моем понимании виджет - это некий универсальны механизм, который должен быть независимым от проекта. А, тут сразу две зависимости. Он должен знать о том, что в проекте существует ContactForm, а, так-же, знать как и куда отправлять данные после успешной валидации.

Впрочем, если сделать эти зависимости настраиваемыми, то можно и виджет.

Comment: Это сильно у вас захардкоженый способ. Таких блоков с разными формами на разных страницах может быть уйма и в разных комбинациях и навеска всего этого на базовый контроллер выглядит неверной.

Comment: Естественно, все зависит от ситуации. Предложенный способ решает вопрос обработки формы которая должна быть на каждой странице.

Для комбинации форм можно сделать настраиваемый виджет куда будет передаваться имя модели и колбек для обработки валидных данных.

Comment: 1) Я не спрашивал о форме которая на всех страницах. 
Таких "везде нужных" форм я и не встречал никогда.

2) значит все таки виджет.

Comment: 2. Как один из вариантов. Не вижу ничего страшного в том, чтобы в частном случае отклониться от MVC, если MVC не предлагает эффективного решения задачи.

Comment: Единственно, с виджетами важно учитывать то, что они выполняются в представлениях, а значит в последнюю очередь. Если контроллер не дойдет до рендера вьюва, то и виджет не обработается...

Answer (score 1):

Указывай action в формах с обращением туда, куда тебе нужно и тогда не будет никаких проблем. Для логина можешь создать свою модель обработки формы с помощью gii.